# How to get Ruby twitter to check friendship relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, twitter-follow, social-network-friendship

How do I make the `friendship` method work with the Twitter gem to check the relationships of users friends and or followers? The error says there are no parameters.

My code is:

```
require 'twitter'
require 'rubygems'

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key = "..."
  config.consumer_secret = "..."
  config.access_token = "..."
  config.access_token_secret = "..."
end
```

EDIT :

```
puts client.friendship('user1','user2').to_s
```

Response:

```
#<Twitter::Relationship:0x007f88c1e58de0>
```

How can I extract the hash response to a readable output i.e. boolean to let me know what its suppose to be saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sferik/twitter/master/Twitter/REST/FriendsAndFollowers:friendship

According to the documentation, it appears you're using the wrong method and passing incorrect parameters. The parameters are not a hash with the keys 'source' and 'target', they're simply two strings representing the source and target users.

Calling `Twitter::REST::FriendsAndFollowers.friendship('user1', 'user2')` should return a Twitter::Relationship object containing information about the relationship between the two users.

**EDIT**

Calling `client.friendship?('user1', 'user2')` returns true if user1 follows user2, and false is otherwise.

Comment: I don't have access to the gem to try it atm but I believe you should be able to call either `client.friendship('user2')` or `client.friendship('user1', 'user2')` @marriedjane875

Comment: is client supposed to equal the Twitter::REST::FriendsAndFollowers ? @markchandler

Comment: i.e. 
    client = Twitter::REST::FreindsAndFollowers.friendship('user1', 'user2')

Comment: i keep getting undefined method error :\ @markchandler

Comment: How can I extract the hash response to a readable output i.e. boolean to let me know what its suppose to be saying? @markchandler

Comment: How can I extract the hash response to a readable output i.e. boolean to let me know what its suppose to be saying? @thetinman

Comment: From the docs: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sferik/twitter/master/Twitter/REST/FriendsAndFollowers#friendship?-instance_method  


`client.friendship?('user1', 'user2')` returns true if user1 follows user2, and false if not.

Comment: Hey thanks guy, yeah I finally was able to do it... But do you also know if I can check attributes such as when the friendship was 'created_at'?